# how to write sql query text for IN clause in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to know how can I write a sql query in C# where I have to use multiple strings in the IN clause.

I have a List ListSessionId, and I want to use each of them in my IN clause.

Something like:

```
foreach (var sessionid in ListSessionId)
{
    query = " SELECT OM.ORDERCONFIRMATIONID AS OCN ";
    query += " FROM [DGS].[DGSCRM].[LEAD] ";
    query += " WHERE ";
    query += " SESSIONID in ('" + sessionid + "') ";
}
```

so as my query is something like:

```
SELECT OM.ORDERCONFIRMATIONID AS OCN
FROM [DGS].[DGSCRM].[LEAD]
WHERE
SESSIONID in ('sessionid1', 'sessionid2', 'sessionid3')
```

Comment: if the content of `ListSessionId` is directly or indirectly user provided, you are facing a possible SQL Injection attack.

Comment: @Jamiec wow, I disagree with **all** of those listed duplicates; don't get me wrong - this is certainly a common question, but those are all miles away

Comment: @MarcGravell do you think? Hmm. ok. Happy to be proved wrong - if its a common question what are the *right* dupes?

Comment: @Huma are you open to using external tools like "Dapper"? Dapper would make this absolutely trivial: `var ids = connection.Query<int>(@"SELECT OM.ORDERCONFIRMATIONID AS OCN     FROM 
 [DGS].[DGSCRM].[LEAD]    WHERE SESSIONID in @sessions", new { sessions = ListSessionId }).AsList();`

Comment: @Jamiec looking now, but this is basically "how to add parameterize an `in`", which isn't the same as those - it might involve multiple parameters

Comment: @MarcGravell No, no external tools

Comment: check answer try now

Comment: I can't actually find a direct duplicate - although I'm sure they exist; the short answer is: build SQL with an `IN` statement that references multiple parameters, one per item in the list - and add parameters to your command with the values from the list. So the query might end up as `where foo in (@x0, @x1, @x2)` and you add 3 parameters

Comment: Still think mine were the right duplicates - explaining not how to solve *this particular case* but the problem in general.

Comment: Note In has a cap (at least in Oracle) of 1000 items as such if you are envisioning a large amount you may want to switch to or = instead of in. Also look up parameter binding especially if this is coming from user input to avoid sql injection

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While you can solve this with a string `.join` or just iterating your loop to build the stuff between the parentheses in your `IN` clause, it will leave you wide open for SQL injection.

To avoid that you MUST parameterize your inputs to the SQL string. We do this by using the sql command `.Parameters` class.

It will look something like:

```
var query = "SELECT OM.ORDERCONFIRMATIONID AS OCN FROM [DGS].[DGSCRM].[LEAD] SESSIONID in ({0})"; 

var idParameterList = new List<string>();
var index = 0;
foreach (var sessionid in ListSessionId)
{
    var paramName = "@idParam" + index;
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, sessionid);
    idParameterList.Add(paramName);
    index++;
}
sqlCommand.CommandText = String.Format(query, string.Join(",", idParameterList));
```

Note that I'm totally guessing at your `sqlCommand` variable name, but you can swap that out as needed.

With this we are splitting our SQL string/command up into two chunks

1. The sql itself. This ends up being submitted to the database looking like `SELECT OM.ORDERCONFIRMATIONID AS OCN FROM [DGS].[DGSCRM].[LEAD] SESSIONID in (@idParam0, @idParam1, @idParam3, ... @idParamN)`. The database gets this sql string and compiles it as if it had values in it. It determines the execution path and just sits on it waiting for the values to come through in the second part
2. The parameter's values come in. This is the list we are building in the loop. Each value in your `ListSessionId` gets paired up with a new `sqlCommand.Parameters` which takes a name `@idParam0` or `@idParam1`, etc.

Because your SQL is compiled without any of the actual stuff in your `ListSessionID` there is no way for bad SQL to show up and get executed in your database. It's compiled and ready to execute. So when the parameters hit, it runs the plan for the sql statement and barfs back results. Nice and clean.

Comment: The fifth line should be "foreach (var sessionid in ListSessionId)"

Comment: @Ruyut Thanks for spotting that. I have updated the answer with the edit.

Comment: Keep in mind if you have a large list, the max amount of parameters is 2100. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 6):

You can solve this with Linq and using parameters which is critical to ensuring your code is safe from Sql Injection attacks. When using parameters be sure to also specify the parameter type and the length if applicable. I guessed at a length of 100 and a type of `VarChar`, you can adjust this as necessary.

```
// create the parameters
var parameters = ListSessionId.Select((sessionId, indx) => new SqlParameter("@session_" + indx, SqlDbType.VarChar, 100) {Value = sessionId}).ToArray();
// create the query
command.CommandText = $"SELECT OM.ORDERCONFIRMATIONID AS OCN FROM [DGS].[DGSCRM].[LEAD] WHERE SESSIONID IN ({string.Join(",", parameters.Select(x=>x.ParameterName))})";
// add parameters to the command
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
```

Comment: Totally digging the Lambda. And the `.AddRange()` method. That's elegant. I'm going to steal that.