# SQL WHERE IN does not work with List<string>

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core

when I run my SQL query directly I have to issues:

```
SELECT [hostname]
  FROM [ComputerImport]
  where LOWER(SUBSTRING (computerimport.hostname, 1, 2)) in ('DE', 'FR') AND computerimport.hostname LIKE '%'
```

but when I try to do it out of c# I get no results

```
string searchString = ""
List<string> allowedStatus = new List<string>();
allowedStatus.Add("de");
            string sqlquery = "SELECT computerimport.hostname FROM ComputerImport WHERE LOWER(SUBSTRING (computerimport.hostname, 1, 2)) in ({1}) AND (computerimport.hostname LIKE '%' + {0} + '%') ";                          

_context.OverviewQueries.FromSqlRaw(sqlquery, searchString, string.Join(",", allowedStatus.Select(s => "'" + s + "'").ToArray()));
```

I also tried:

```
string.Join(",", allowedStatus.Select(s => "'" + s + "'")
string.Join(",", allowedStatus)
string.Join(",", allowedStatus)ToArray()
```

What works is:

```
_context.OverviewQueries.FromSqlRaw(sqlquery, searchString, "DE");
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to write sql query text for IN clause in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858620/how-to-write-sql-query-text-for-in-clause-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Also, your code is open to a SQL injection attack. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892166/how-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: because you are using formatted  version - you are basically sending one string which is wrong. You either change into  SQL command or create finallize string before execution

Answer (score 0):

You may use basic linq, FromSqlRaw is more for using Table Valued Functions etc.

```
string searchString = ""
List<string> allowedStatus = new List<string>();
allowedStatus.Add("de");

return _context.ComputerImport
  .Where(o => o.hostname != null && allowedStatus.Contains(o.hostname.Substring(0,2).ToLower()))
  .Where(o => o.hostname.Contains(searchString));
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, I did not post the whole query but I am also using GROUP BY and STRING_AGG, thats whay I am using SQL

Comment: [Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results) is also in Linq, string class contains [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1) method

Comment: but not STRING_AGG or group_concat, or am I missing something? I tried it with LINQ but I got crazy

Comment: So you should ask question like "How to get result like STRING_AGG for GROUP BY SQL query using linq?" and add minimum reproducible example in description. But it may be duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60007040/converting-t-sql-string-agg-to-linq-c-sharp

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. But that way I just dont get it working. I am always getting a GroupByShaperExpression, or when I just follow the example that in the last var the columns do not exist.
Regarding the injection, I read that it is enough to put a $ before the query, I also tried putting different SQL statements in the query, no problem so far.